# Using Java: Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000. (What’s wrong with my algorithm?)

Tags: java

I'm getting 266333, but that isn't the right answer. I don't see the flaw in my algorithm, though.

```
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i=i+3) {
        count = count + i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i=i+5) {
        count = count + i;
    }

    System.out.println(count);
```

EDIT: I posted this because I saw other algorithms using modulus, but not approaching it this way. I felt like this theory was valid, but I was missing a piece.

Comment: see the update for more efficient code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting numbers like 15, 30... (which are multiple of both 3 and 5) two times. So one alternative is to subtract these counts, you can add following loop after your two loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i+=15) {
    count-=i;
}
```

You can also do the same in one loop (More efficient):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if(i%15 == 0) count+=i;   
    else if(i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0) count += i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're double-counting all of the numbers that are multiples of both 3 and 5.

Comment: So would finding the numbers that are duplicates, then subtracting it from the count be an efficient method?

Comment: No, don't add and then subtract. It won't be that efficient. Alternative is only count multiples of both 3 and 5 once.

Answer (score 0):

This is the typical case of Universal Law of Addition for not Mutually Exclusive events as The Events A="Number of Multiples of 3" and B= "Number of Multiples of 5" are not mutually exclusive. Meaning thereby that they have LCM(Least Common Multiple) 15. So when you are counting multiples of 3 you are also counting multiple of LCM (that is 15). Similarly when you are counting multiple of 5 you are again counting LCM'multiple(that is 15).

A very naive solution is to make a third  loop but this time for multiple of 15 and this time subtract i(count of 15) from the count variable.

Comment: No need to use separate variables.